# Using StoreContext.CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates when the network is disconnected will cause the app to crash

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

Strangely, try catch can't catch this exception, so I don't know what to do.

Code snippet:

```
[System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
public bool CanSilentlyUpdate()
{
    try
    {
        // Disable the network before executing this method, and an exception is thrown:
        //     System.AccessViolationException :“Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
        //     This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.”
        // Then the app crashes
        return StoreContext.GetDefault().CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Some error log in event viewer:

> Application: MyApp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
> process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
> System.AccessViolationException at
> Windows.Services.Store.StoreContext.get_CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates()

I know that I can determine whether to call `StoreContext.CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdatesby` judging the network status, but when I use `StoreContext.TrySilentDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync` to upgrade the app, if the network is disabled during the upgrade process, the app will still crash.

I think this is the same kind of problem, so I hope there can be a better way to solve it.

Comment: Hello, the `TrySilentDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync` method will start a silent download. When the method is finished, it means that the download has started. If an exception occurs due to network problems during the download process, the Try-Catch placed on this method may not catch the exception. You can try to handle the `App.UnhandledException` event, Uncaught exceptions within the app will eventually bubble up here.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Hello, Richard, Thank you for your reply, but why can't I use Try-catch to catch the exception caused by CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates? I think these two methods raise the same exception (perhaps an unmanaged exception?), so neither can be caught.

Comment: Forgot to say, my app is the desktop bridge app, I can use the App.Dispatcher.UnhandledException to catch the error I throw, but can not catch System.AccessViolationException

Comment: I wrote a very simple demo and uploaded it to [onedriver](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak6Tub3_nRs96F-9PUtS_XWYREIs?e=nP4nEj), you can directly reproduce the problem, if you can take a moment to help me look at it, it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion with the engineers, it was concluded that at present, the exception in the background thrown by `StoreContext.TrySilentDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync` cannot be caught in the UI thread.

The currently recommended method is to check the network availability before performing this method ([NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.networkstatuschanged?view=winrt-19041)). When the network status changes, the user is required to perform the download again. Or use the [RequestDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.requestdownloadstorepackageupdatesasync?view=winrt-19041) method located in the UI thread to execute the download request.